# "System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'" when reading image from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have images assigned to every button in my VB.NET form, the images come from SQL Server. The data type is `varbinary(MAX)`.

This is my code:

```vb
Using con As New SqlConnection("con string")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE ID=@ID"
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 3
        con.Open()
        Using myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If myreader.Read() AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(myreader("Image")) Then
                Boton3.Text = myreader("Item")
                Boton3.Enabled = myreader("ONOFF")
                Dim ImgSql() As Byte = DirectCast(myreader("Image"), Byte())
                Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
                    Boton3.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            Else
                Boton3.Text = myreader("Item")
                Boton3.BackgroundImage = Nothing
                Boton3.Enabled = myreader("ONOFF")
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

The platform is 64bit. I'm thinking it might have to do with not disposing properly, but I'm not sure since I'm new to coding.

**EDIT SHOWING NEW CODE AND HOW I RETRIVE MORE THAN ONE RECORD:**

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Try
            dt = GetInventoryDataByID(1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Boton1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Articulo").ToString
            Boton1.Enabled = CBool(dt.Rows(0)("ONOFF"))
            If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows(0)("Imagen")) Then
                Dim ImgSql() As Byte = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)("Imagen"), Byte())
                Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
                    Boton1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
                End Using
            Else
                Boton1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No records returned")
        End If
        Dim dt2 As DataTable
        Try
            dt2 = GetInventoryDataByID(2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        If dt2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Boton2.Text = dt2.Rows(0)("Articulo").ToString
            Boton2.Enabled = CBool(dt2.Rows(0)("ONOFF"))
            If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(dt2.Rows(0)("Imagen")) Then
                Dim ImgSql() As Byte = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(0)("Imagen"), Byte())
                Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
                    Boton2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
                End Using
            Else
                Boton2.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No records returned")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function GetInventoryDataByID(id As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Imagen, Articulo, ONOFF FROM Inventario WHERE ID=@ID"
        Using con As New SqlConnection("CON STRING"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
            con.Open()
            Using myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                dt.Load(myreader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Just FYI an [interesting article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/07/store-files-in-a-file-system-not-a-relational-database/)

Comment: That error message can also mean that there was something wrong with the data. If you save the data to disk, can you open it as an image with something like IrfanView?

Comment: What line does the code error on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am able to open the image on another software called photo paint.

Comment: @howdy That's good, it eliminates one possible problem. Next, if you create a stream from that image on disk and use that instead of the data from the database, does it work?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry for the late reply. Do you mean adding the picture manually? For example going to the properties tab in visual studio and adding the image there? It does work. But the issue is not one specific image, its adding more than one image that causes the error.

Comment: @howdy That's OK, we all have other tasks between looking at Stack Overflow :) As Mary asked earlier, *exactly* which line does the error happen on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The error happens as soon as I load the form. It doesn't show which line of code it errors on, but it does show `Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).`

Comment: @howdy Oh Noes! How are we ever going to find the problem? So, what makes you think that the code you are showing in the question is the problem? Did you comment out the code that retrieves an image? (Please bear in mind that we can't see over the surveillance cam that views your monitor at the moment due to maintenance.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes exactly. I commented out sections of code, and I came to the conclusion by using process of elimination. I also noticed that when the image column is null in SQL it does work. I assume that's the issue, its unfortunate that the surveillance cam wasn't able to capture this in 4k :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to hold a connection open while you update the user interface. Separate you user interface code from your database code.

If you put a comma at the end of the first line of the outer Using block, both the command and the connection are included in same block. Saves a bit of indenting.

You are passing an integer to the `@ID` parameter but you have set the `SqlDbType` as a `VarChar`. Looks like a problem. I changed the `SqlDbType` to `Int`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = GetInventoryDataByID(3)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Boton3.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Item").ToString
        Boton3.Enabled = CBool(dt.Rows(0)("ONOFF"))
        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows(0)("Image")) Then
            Dim ImgSql() As Byte = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
            Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
                Boton3.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
            End Using
        Else
            Boton3.BackgroundImage = Nothing
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No records returned")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetInventoryDataByID(id As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE ID=@ID"
    Using con As New SqlConnection("con string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
        con.Open()
        Using myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(myreader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

EDIT Add Dispose on image

```
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows(0)("Image")) Then
        Dim ImgSql() As Byte = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
            If Boton3.BackgroundImage IsNot Nothing Then
                Boton3.BackgroundImage.Dispose()
            End If
            Boton3.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    Else
        If Boton3.BackgroundImage IsNot Nothing Then
            Boton3.BackgroundImage.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I tried your solution on a `mybase.load` event. I still get the same error. The error only happens when more than one button has a image (15 buttons in total). The error also happens as soon as I load the form. It doesn't show which line of code it errors on, but it does show `Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).`

Comment: Your code shows returning a single record. Show the code where you are retrieving more than one record. For testing purposes move the code out of `Form_Load` and stick a button on the form to perform the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mary. I edited my question to show how I retrieve more than one record. I also tested the operation on a `Button_Click` and the same error appeared.

Comment: I added calling Dispose on the Image. This may help the memory problems.

Comment: I resolved this issue by simply not using buttons. Instead I used pictureboxes as buttons and that resolved the issue. I'm guessing the problem is that buttons don't allow as much memory as pictureboxes. I will still accept your answer since I learned a lot from your code. Thank you Mary!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by simply not using buttons. Instead I used pictureboxes as buttons and that resolved the issue. Im guesssing the problem is that buttons don't allow as much memory as pictureboxes.